# Return head node of a linked list in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have the following Linked List implementation:

```
class LinkedList
  def initialize
    @head = nil
  end

  def return_head
    previous_head = @head
    previous_head.next = nil # I want to return a clean node, without nexts
    @head = @head.next
    return previous_head
  end

  def add_element(value)
    if @head.nil?
      @head = Node.new(value)
    else
      new_node = Node.new(value)
      @head.next = new_node
    end
  end

end

class Node
  attr_accessor :data, :next
  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
  end
end
```

My problem is in the return_head method. When I do `previous_head.next = nil`, because I want to return a single Node, the head itself, without next. Since I set the next to nil, then when I do `@head = @head.next`, `@head` is `nil`

How could I solve this?

Comment: Do you want to call `return_head` two or more times in a row without intervening calls to `add_element`; e.g., `add_element('dog'); add_element('cat'); add_element('pig'); return_head; return_head`? Your answer will have an important bearing on the kind of data structure that is needed. Also, are you sure you want the object `@head` returned (with `@head.next = nil`) or just `@head.data`?  I don't see what you'd do with an object that is no longer in the linked list, other than extract `data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you treat `@head` and `previous_head` as if they were different objects, but they are not.

When you call

```
previous_head.next = nil # I want to return a clean node, without nexts
```

the `next` attribute of `previous_head` (and consequently of `@head`) is set to `nil`, so when you try to access it again from `@head` it is already `nil`.

To solve this you need to reverse the order of operations, first setting the new `@head` and only then removing the `next` node from the `previous_head`:

```
  def return_head
    previous_head = @head
    @head = @head.next
    previous_head.next = nil # I want to return a clean node, without nexts
    return previous_head
  end
```

On a side note, you might also want to look at @Cary's answer, as your `add_element` method does not actually add an element, but rather replaces the second element (you'll have a list of zero, one or two element - no more...)

Answer (score 0):

```
def return_head
  previous_head = @head
  next_head = @head.next
  @head.next = nil # I want to return a clean node, without nexts
  @head = next_head
  return previous_head
end
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problems

`add_elements` has a bug: `@head` is never changed after the first element is added, only `@head.next` is changed.

Even with `add_elements` fixed, however, you cannot execute `return_head` twice without an intervening `add_element`. If `return` head is never invoked twice in a row, you may as well implement a simple stack.

To execute `return_head` two or more times in a row, you need to save the first node of the list and use `node.next` to step through the list until the next-to-last node is found.  I have done this below, under *Single Linked List*.

When deleting a node, I chose to return `node.data`, rather than `node`, because the latter has been severed from the list, so all you can do with it is extract `data`.

Your other option is to implement a double linked list, which I have also done below.

### Single Linked List

**Code**

```
class SingleLinkedList
  attr_reader :head

  def initialize
    @head = nil
    @tail = nil
  end

  def delete_and_return_head
    data = @head.data
    delete_head
    data
  end

  def delete_head
    return if @head.nil?
    if @start == @head
      @start = nil
      @head = nil
    else
      @head = find_prev
      @head.next = nil
    end
  end

  def add_element(value)
    new_node = Node.new(value)
    if @head.nil?
      @start = new_node
    else
      @head.next = new_node
    end  
    @head = new_node
  end

private

  def find_prev
    node = @start
    node = node.next while node.next.next
    node
  end

end

class Node
  attr_accessor :data, :next
  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
  end
end
```

**Example**

*Create linked list*

```
l = SingleLinkedList.new #=> #<SingleLinkedList:0x0000010200be70 @head=nil, @tail=nil>
```

*Add elements*

```
l.add_element(:dog)      #=> #<Node:0x0000010184cbf8 @data=:dog>
l.head                   #=> #<Node:0x0000010184cbf8 @data=:dog>
l.head.data              #=> :dog
l.head.next              #=> nil
dog = l.head             #=> #<Node:0x0000010184cbf8 @data=:dog>

l.add_element(:cat)      #=> #<Node:0x00000102207da0 @data=:cat>
l.head.data              #=> :cat
dog.next.data            #=> :cat
cat = l.head             #=> #<Node:0x00000102207da0 @data=:cat>

l.add_element(:pig)      #=> #<Node:0x000001021e4dc8 @data=:pig>
l.head.data              #=> :pig
cat.next.data            #=> :pig
```

*Delete and return elements*

```
l.delete_and_return_head #=> :pig
l.head.data              #=> :cat
l.head.next              #=> nil

l.delete_and_return_head #=> :cat
l.head.data              #=> :dog
l.head.next              #=> nil
```

### Double Linked List

**Code**

```
class DoubleLinkedList
  attr_reader :head

  def initialize
    @head = nil
  end

  def delete_and_return_head
    data = @head.data
    delete_head
    data
  end

  def delete_head
    return nil if @head.nil?
    if @head.prev.nil?
      @head = nil
    else
      @head.prev.next = nil
      @head = @head.prev
    end
  end  

  def add_element(value)
    new_node = Node.new(value)
    unless @head.nil?
      new_node.prev = @head
      @head.next = new_node
    end  
    @head = new_node
  end
end
```

.

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :data, :next, :prev
  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
  end
end
```

**Example**

*Create linked list*

```
l = DoubleLinkedList.new #=> #<DoubleLinkedList:0x00000101048a60 @head=nil>
```

*Add elements*

```
l.add_element(:dog)      #=> #<Node:0x00000101039a60 @data=:dog>
l.head                   #=> #<Node:0x00000101039a60 @data=:dog>
l.head.data              #=> :dog
l.head.prev              #=> nil
l.head.next              #=> nil
dog = l.head             #=> #<Node:0x00000101039a60 @data=:dog>

l.add_element(:cat)      #=> #<Node:0x00000101874450 @data=:cat,
                         #    @prev=#<Node:0x00000101039a60 @data=:dog>>
l.head.data              #=> :cat
l.head.prev.data         #=> :dog
dog.next.data            #=> :cat
cat = l.head             #=> #<Node:0x00000101874450 @data=:cat,
                         #    @prev=#<Node:0x00000101039a60 @data=:dog>>

l.add_element(:pig)      #=> #<Node:0x00000101110fb0 @data=:pig,
                         #    @prev=#<Node:0x00000101874450 @data=:cat,
                         #    @next=#<Node:0x00000101110fb0 ...>,
                         #    @prev=#<Node:0x00000101039a60 @data=:dog>>>
l.head.data              #=> :pig
l.head.prev.data         #=> :cat
cat.next.data            #=> :pig
```

*Delete and return elements*

```
l.delete_and_return_head #=> :pig

l.head.data              #=> :cat
l.head.next              #=> nil
l.head.prev.data         #=> :dog
dog.next.data            #=> :cat

l.delete_and_return_head #=> :cat

l.head.data              #=> :dog
l.head.next              #=> nil
l.head.prev              #=> nil
```